# Best BarCodeOptions for detecting dense PDF417 barcodes on iOS using Camera.MAUI?

Tags: maui, ios-camera, pdf417

Having trouble with a vanilla C#/.NET/MAUI app that uses Camera.MAUI to detect PDF417 barcodes on iOS.  I can detect simple codes like [this](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Better_Sample_PDF417.svg), but no luck with the denser barcodes on driver licenses.

My setup for the cameraView (Camera.MAUI.CameraView) in the ContentPage is:

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        cameraView.CamerasLoaded += CameraView_CamerasLoaded;

        cameraView.BarcodeDetected += CameraView_BarcodeDetected;
        cameraView.BarCodeOptions = new Camera.MAUI.ZXingHelper.BarcodeDecodeOptions
        {
            AutoRotate = true,
            PossibleFormats = {ZXing.BarcodeFormat.PDF_417},
            ReadMultipleCodes = false,
            TryHarder = true,
            TryInverted = true
        };
        cameraView.BarCodeDetectionFrameRate = 10;
        cameraView.BarCodeDetectionMaxThreads = 5;
        cameraView.ControlBarcodeResultDuplicate = true;
        cameraView.BarCodeDetectionEnabled = true;
    }
```

CameraView_BarcodeDetected simply presents an alert when a barcode is detected.  It fires for simple barcodes, but never for the barcodes found on US driver licenses.

I suspect the answer lies in using different value for BarCodeDetectionFrameRate and BarCodeDetectionMaxThreads, but haven't found the special mix yet in testing on several different iPhone 14 devices.  Has anyone else been able to detect driver license barcodes on iOS using Camera.MAUI?

Comment: I'd suggest reading some of the existing questions on reading PDF417 in native iOS and find the right mix of native options, then figure out how to translate those into parameters for MAUI.

Comment: Thank you @Jason for the speedy reply.  That was actually my first move.  However it looks like the Camera.MAUI impl of BarcodeReader.Decode/DecodeMultiple is a separate thing (using ZXing).   The example BarCodeOptions above is straight out of the project's readme (https://github.com/hjam40/Camera.MAUI/tree/d9ee42a428b9ee41efff624fe01643b62c7781e6).  I'm guessing that these settings work most of the time.  They certainly work for simple(r) QR and PDF417 barcodes.  It's the denser ones (like on the back of a driver license) that aren't detected.  I'll keep digging...